# Real Time Refresh / Update

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a MVC 3 project that publish in a server.

**Scenario**

For example I have a function for saving a data from `(PC1)` to `(PC2)`.

It is possible that the viewing of `data(data in jqgrid)` in `(PC2)` is `open(open in page)` by a user and it will auto refresh or update the page or the jqgrid after the `(PC1)` save a data?

My jqgrid version is `4.3.3`.

Hope you guys understand what I mean in my post. Post feedback if down votes. Thanks.

Any help will be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

**You might wonna use ajax to accomplish such a job, please read below**

if I understand what you mean, is that you wonna poll a server to realtime updates on either intervals or something else...

**option 1**
Issue a normal stateless ajax call to the server, then force the server to hold the request for a limited time *[to overcome server overhead]*

This can also be reffered to as reverse ajax or comet. 
Unless you are planning to use websocket technology, I hardly stress that you try this.

Comment: Can you provide me an example if possible?. Because I am just learning the web programming world.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_GET['finite'])){
#declare time for a session
$_SESSION['typing']=$reduce_browser_overhead=time();
#remember to close the session before entering the loop;
#if u dont close, then the browser will not reload the same website untill the connection is close or satisfied
session_write_close();
function loop(){
    #do this to access external variables  ===> $reduce_browser_overhead;
    global $con,$reduce_browser_overhead;
    #explicitly check 2exit
    #please do this to release mysql connection since they are in a loop
    if($reduce_browser_overhead+4<time()){
        echo ' ';ob_flush();flush();
        if(connection_aborted()){
            #do some work here before you finally exit the connection
            exit;
        }$reduce_browser_overhead=time();
    }
    #php prepare statement...
    $looper=$con->prepare("SELECT ROW FROM TABLE WHERE ID=SOMETHING AND $_SESSION[typing]=SOME_ROW");
    #The statement above willcause the loop to work
    #If a table had been update and table has not yet updated, this sql will detemin by the current time
    #meaning that if the time[integer] of SOME_ROW is not equal to the time in the session variable,
    #then it will let go to the client and then again it will continue looping untill the time in the
    #SOME TABLE ROW  changes....

    $looper->execute();
    $looper->store_result();
    if($looper->num_rows>0){
        sleep(2);
        #do some work before looping again
        loop();
        #you have to explicitly return to this loop to work as expected.
        return;
    }else{
        #send back data to the user or the client listening on the connection
        session_start();$_SESSION['typing']=time();session_write_close();
        #update the session before finishing the request so that the next time the request comes, the time will be equal to the DBserver time in the row and hence causing the loop again and again => more like a cycle
        echo 'After some time the server has received new data which is =>> '.$newdata;
    }
}loop();
exit;
```

```js
 //In another file on in the same document as the php / your server file  ==> do javascript below
    //first issue a normal / stateless ajax request to the target server
    $.ajax({
        //All optional but url required!
        url:'abc.php?var_one=blabla',
        cache:true,//whether to cache the requests
        timeout:(1000*60)*20,//timeoutthe request
        success:function(data){
            //if the server successfully completed the request
            //do some work here with data returned
        },
        error:function(){
            //if the server return an error
            //do more work around
            //or call the function again
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: why there is a code for PHP but i didn't ask for it?